# Using conditions based on two different columns to determine whether cell is highlighted or not

Tags: conditional-formatting

I have column K that indicates the follow-up due dates and I want them to highlight if the date in column K is before today, AND if the cell in column M (same row) is blank. In my mind it sounds like this:
If cell in column M is blank and cell in column K is before today, highlight red with red text.
This is what I want it to do.

[image]

I have googled numerous things to try and nothing seems to work